# FCM notification icon issue for oreo

Tags: java, android

I am Using FCM to send push notification to the user. That notification is coming properly for below Oreo versions. In Oreo also notification is coming properly but sometimes notification icon is not showing properly. This was happened in One Plus 3T device. I specified notification channel also for Oreo version.

Comment: post any screenshot and your code here , let us see what have you done so far

Comment: Please find the screen shot of notification tray https://imgur.com/a/12dyj